# Using emojis in TextViews... Does they change between Android versions?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, emoji

I'm testing to use Emojis in textviews like this:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/text_button_background"
        android:text="&#10134;"
        android:textSize="@dimen/medium_text">
```

It works perfectly, because I need to create a "+" and a "-" textviews with exactly the same width and the width of them are different because minus character is thinner than plus character.

The problem is: will emojis change if they are executed in different android devices? or will be always the same emoji I'm seeing now while compiling?

Comment: Have you seen https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/emoji-compat ?

Comment: @BenP. I'm not using emoji compat libraries, just drawing in a textview using decimal code, without adding any libraries